# Не понимаю в чем дело, почему вес файла соответствует ,а качество нет

Tags: ffmpeg

Скачал видео с ютуба. Видео имеет качество 1080, формат webm, вес файла составляет 46 мб.

Задача в том, чтобы пропустить через ffmpeg, получить на выходе формат webm и вес файла 46мб. При этом не потерять качество.

Команда которую применяю

```
ffmpeg -i 1080.webm -c:a libvorbis -ab 196k -c:v libvpx -maxrate 9000k -bufsize 9000k -vf scale=-2:1080 /webm/1080.webm
```

Высота кадара на входе 1080, на выходе 1080, вес файла 46. А вот качество, будто 240 вместо 1080.
Версия кодека libvpx 1.6, сейчас обновляю до 1.9. Но думаю тут дело не в версии кодека, в чем может быть дело?

Какой битрейт необходимо выставлять? При конвертации в mp4 его не применял, использовал -maxrate -bufsize, выполняли задачу на ура и при низких значениях.